# Nancy + SignalR

Tags: c#, signalr, nancy

Проблема была в том, что любые попытки подключиться к хабу заканчивались ответом сервера 404 (not found). Код в `Startup` был следующий:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    AppContext.SetSwitch("Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior", true);
    AppContext.SetSwitch("Npgsql.DisableDateTimeInfinityConversions", true);

    app.UseOwin(x => x.UseNancy());

    app.UseEndpoints(endPoint =>
    {
        endPoint.MapHub<OrderHub>("/ordersNotification");
    });
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
    {
        options
            .UseNpgsql(_configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                assembly =>
                    assembly.MigrationsAssembly("ASPHost"));
    });

    ConfigureRepository.ConfigureService(services);
    ConfigureServiceBase.ConfigureService(services);
    ConfigureMapper.ConfigureService(services);
    ConfigureController.ConfigureService(services);
    ConfigureCache.ConfigureService(services);

    services.AddSignalR();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Решение, на которое я потратил почти 2 суток, оказалось крайне простым - поменять местами `UseOwin...` и `UseEndpoints...`. Итого, метод `Configure` должен выглядеть следующим образом:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    AppContext.SetSwitch("Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior", true);
    AppContext.SetSwitch("Npgsql.DisableDateTimeInfinityConversions", true);

    app.UseEndpoints(endPoint =>
    {
        endPoint.MapHub<OrderHub>("/ordersNotification");
    });

    app.UseOwin(x => x.UseNancy());
}
```

Надеюсь, этот ответ сможет спасти чью-нибудь ж*пу от сгорания